# Django query taking a long time to run

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I have created a query in get_context of a Class Based View from which I generate a dict I send into a Django template to display alongside a formset.  The number of records returned is about 40 and it takes about 5 seconds to run - which will translate to 30 or 40 seconds with a full set of data.  Looking at Django Debug Toolbar SQL queries, it is continuing to run 40 additional queries despite adding what look like the correct select_related and prefetch_related for the reverse related table to my queryset.

My models (simplified for this example):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class ItemLocSite(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class ItemLoc(AbstractAddArchive):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    iloc = models.ForeignKey(ItemLocSite, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='iloc')
    nloc = models.ForeignKey(ItemLocSite, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='nloc')
    cp_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item}"

class ItemInfo(AbstractAddArchive):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    log_entry = models.ForeignKey(Log, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    crec_log_entry = models.ForeignKey(InvLog, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='crec_log_entry', blank=True, null=True)
    csts = models.ForeignKey(ItemSts, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    cfill = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comment1 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    comment2 = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    posted_ts = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('item',)  # This sets initial order of formset display

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item_id}"
```

Ideally, ItemLoc and ItemInfo would be one table which would make things much easier, but for system usage reasons it is a system requirement to keep the data in two tables each related to Item, so that's what I have to work with.

My query and dict construction:

```
itemdict = {}
iteminfos = ItemInfo.objects.all().select_related('item').prefetch_related('item__itemloc_set').order_by('item_id')
for iteminfo in iteminfos:
    itemdict[iteminfo.item.name] = iteminfo.item.itemloc_set.all().first().iloc_id
context['itemdict'] = itemdict
```

There will only be 1 active iteminfo for every active itemloc - the query would not work without adding .first() even though it's the only one

In Django Debug Toolbar I see this SQL query running once for each record (there are only 40 now, but will likely be 200 or more which translates into many more queries)

> SELECT ••• FROM "app_itemloc" WHERE ("app_itemloc"."archive_id" IS
> NULL AND "app_itemloc"."item_id" = 'AAA') ORDER BY "app_itemloc"."id"
> ASC LIMIT 1
>
> 40 similar queries.

This query runs for each active item in the system - currently 40.  Each individual query runs quickly, but going back to the database so many times for one page increases the page load time by about 5 seconds.

The archive_id is handled by a custom object used to archive records so only active records show up (see models - ItemInfo and ItemLoc inherit from AbstractAddArchive).  I don't think the archiving should have anything to do with the additional queries, but can provide that additional code if necessary.  - there will never more than 200 or 300 active records.

I would have thought the prefetch of the itemloc set would have pulled the necessary data, but obviously, I am missing a select_related or prefetch_related here, but I cannot see what that would be.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: `itemdict[iteminfo.item.name] = iteminfo.item.itemloc_set.all().first().iloc_id` would obviously make a separate query due to the call to `first()`.

Comment: Thanks for replying - would you have a better way to form the query so that all the data is returned in one sql query knowing there is only 1 record in every itemloc_set?

Comment: If it is guaranteed that there is only one `ItemLoc` instance for an `Item` instance you should be using a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) instead of a foreign key.

Comment: It's only guaranteed for non-archived items in my case - archived items on the table do not allow one to one, so this is the structure I am stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way to get data from both tables without having to use a reverse query or prefetch through the Items table:

```
itemdict = {}
iteminfos = ItemInfo.objects.all().select_related('item').order_by('item_id')
itemlocs = ItemLoc.objects.all().order_by('item_id')
for iteminfo, itemloc in zip(iteminfos, itemlocs):
    itemdict[iteminfo.item_id] = itemloc.iloc_id
context['itemdict'] = itemdict
```

I get the same dict as with my previous construction, but the total number of queries has dropped to 4 and I have shaved about 3.5 seconds off the runtime (with about 45 active entries now).  I was able to use item_id and iloc_id and also avoided having to do a select_related for the values of those since the names are the primary fields of the related tables so the value is the foreign key and not an auto-incremented number.

It seems with the unique structure of the database required in this case, the more standard method using prefetch_related was not an option.  If anyone who reads this does see a way to use prefetch_related, I would still be interested in seeing that.